# Add non-standard tag to DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, jquery-ui, dom

I'm trying to put  tag into JQuery-ui dialog widget. Due to some other problems i need to load this from server as ajax call.

Returned is:

```
    <div id="ajax-body">
    give gift
 <fb:serverFbml width="650px">

  <script type="text/fbml">
  <center>
      <fb:request-form action="${shareGiftUrl}" type="Podíl na Zlaté soše" method="POST"
        content="Daroval jsem ti cuhlu" invite="false">
            <fb:multi-friend-selector cols="4" rows="3" 
             showborder="false" max="1" 
             actiontext="Vyber přítele, kterému chceš darovat podíl a klikni na              'Posílat mi žádosti typu Podíl na Zlaté soše'" 
             email_invite="false" bypass="cancel" import_external_friends="false" 
             exclude_ids="${excludeIds}" />
     </fb:request-form> 
     </center>
     </script>
     </fb:serverFbml>
    </div>
```

if i put this into div prepared for dialog like $(div).html(data):

```
    function loadAjax(url, title) {
 $.get(url,
   function(data) {
    $("#ajaxModal").html(data);
    $("#ajaxModal").show();
    $("#ajaxModal").dialog( {
     modal : true,
     title : title,
     width : 680,
     height : 500,
     close : function(event, ui) {
      $("#ajaxModal").dialog("destroy");
      $("#ajaxModal").html("");
     }
    });
   });
}
```

it deosn't work, the  tag is not in the  tag in the modal dialog.

The script tag is made last child of the body tag - and so is sibling to ui-dialog div

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to insert unparsed FBML into a live browser DOM?

Comment: to parse it :-) (you can parse it anytime with JS SDK) - and I can't put it there upon load, parse it and then create dialog, there is some glitch if the URL for iframe representing the serverFBML tag would be to long (longer hen 2000 chars or so), it ain't working.

Comment: According to my newest research its problem with script tag - can't put it in the middle of the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that jQuery handles sript tags differently then others. If it fidns it in structure passed as parameter of html function it takes it out and run eval on it and then put it at the end of document.

Way around this is to take the script tag and put it in the structure vira normal JavaSript

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/fbml';
script.text = scripttext;
```

It can then be added like

```
$("#ajaxModal").append(script);
```

I'm using regexp to extract script from ajax response